Is my MAML implementation correct?
im trying to implement the MAML algorithm in the Reinforcement Learning domain but am not achieving fast adaptation to my validation tasks.
I assume that something may be wrong with my meta loss computation, and how im calculating the second order gradient. Can someone spot an error in how im implementing this?
class MAMLMetaLearner():
def __init__(self, envs, tasks=5, metaLr=1e-2, metaSteps=100, innerTimeSteps=500, innerLr=5e-2, innerRollouts=20):

    self.envs = envs
    self.env = None
    self.metaLr = metaLr
    self.innerTimeSteps = innerTimeSteps
    self.innerLr = innerLr # inner learning rate is generally higher than the meta learning rate
    self.metaSteps = metaSteps
    self.tasks = tasks # number of tasks to train on per meta iteration
    self.innerRollouts = innerRollouts # number of rollouts for inner loop training

    self.metaAgent = PPO("MLP", self.envs[0], lrAnealling=False, progressBar=False) # meta agent
    self.metaOptimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.metaAgent.actorCritic.parameters(), lr=metaLr)

    self.metaLoss = []

# train the agent on a single task
def ComputeTaskLoss(self, env):

    self.metaAgent.env = env # set the environment for inner loop learning
    
    # adapt the task agent parameters using the task model
    state = None

    # in order to not break the computational graph I will create a dictionary of the inner loop parameters
    adaptedParametersDictionary = {name: parameter for (name, parameter) in self.metaAgent.actorCritic.named_parameters()}

    for step in range(self.innerRollouts):

        state, states, actions, oldLogProbabilities, returns, advantages, _, _ = self.metaAgent.CollectTrajectories(totalTimesteps=self.innerTimeSteps, state=state, parameters = adaptedParametersDictionary, batchSize=self.innerTimeSteps) # collect trajectories using the task agent

        if len(advantages) > 1:
            advantages = (advantages - advantages.mean()) / torch.max(advantages.std(), torch.tensor(1e-9, device=self.metaAgent.device))

        if self.metaAgent.discreteActionSpace:
            actionLogits, values = self.metaAgent.ForwardPass(states, parameters=adaptedParametersDictionary)
            newProbabilityDistribution = Categorical(logits=actionLogits) # using categorical is good because it provides functions to sample and calculate log probabilities
            newLogProbabilities = actionDistribution.log_prob(actions)
        else:
            mean, standardDeviation, values = self.metaAgent.ForwardPass(states, parameters=adaptedParametersDictionary)
            newProbabilityDistribution = torch.distributions.Normal(mean, standardDeviation)
            newLogProbabilities = (newProbabilityDistribution.log_prob(actions)).sum(dim=-1)

        probabilityRatio = torch.exp(newLogProbabilities - oldLogProbabilities) # this is a measure of how much the policy has changed from the old policy

        # compute loss
        loss, _, _, _ = self.metaAgent.ComputeLoss(values, returns, newProbabilityDistribution, probabilityRatio, advantages)

        self.metaAgent.optimizer.zero_grad() # zero the gradients

        # compute gradients with respect to adapted parameters
        gradients = torch.autograd.grad(loss, adaptedParametersDictionary.values(), create_graph=True)           

        # update the adapted parameters using the gradients
        adaptedParametersDictionary = {name: parameter - self.innerLr * gradient for ((name, parameter), gradient) in zip(adaptedParametersDictionary.items(), gradients)}


    # compute loss after adaptation
    _, states, actions, newLogProbabilities, returns, advantages, _, _ = self.metaAgent.CollectTrajectories(totalTimesteps=self.innerTimeSteps, parameters=adaptedParametersDictionary, batchSize=self.innerTimeSteps) # collect trajectories using the updated task agent

    if len(advantages) > 1:
        advantages = (advantages - advantages.mean()) / torch.max(advantages.std(), torch.tensor(1e-9, device=self.metaAgent.device))

    if self.metaAgent.actorCritic.discreteActionSpace:
        actionLogits, _ = self.metaAgent.actorCritic(states)
        actionDistribution = Categorical(logits=actionLogits) # using categorical is good because it provides functions to sample and calculate log probabilities
        oldLogProbabilities = actionDistribution.log_prob(actions)
    else:
        mean, standardDeviation, _ = self.metaAgent.actorCritic(states)
        oldProbabilityDistribution = torch.distributions.Normal(mean, standardDeviation)
        oldLogProbabilities = (oldProbabilityDistribution.log_prob(actions)).sum(dim=-1)

    # calculate newProbabilityDistribution
    if self.metaAgent.actorCritic.discreteActionSpace:
        actionLogits, values = self.metaAgent.ForwardPass(states, parameters=adaptedParametersDictionary)
        newProbabilityDistribution = Categorical(logits=actionLogits)
    else:
        mean, standardDeviation, values = self.metaAgent.ForwardPass(states, parameters=adaptedParametersDictionary)
        newProbabilityDistribution = torch.distributions.Normal(mean, standardDeviation)
       
    probabilityRatio = torch.exp(newLogProbabilities - oldLogProbabilities) # this is a measure of how much the policy has changed from the original policy

    adaptedLoss, _, _, _ = self.metaAgent.ComputeLoss(values, returns, newProbabilityDistribution, probabilityRatio, advantages)

    return adaptedLoss

def MetaTrain(self):
    print("Meta Training Started...")
    count = 0
    smallestLoss = -float("inf")
    for metaIteration in tqdm(range(self.metaSteps), desc="Meta Training Progress", unit = "iterations"):
        metaLoss = 0.0
        tasks = [random.choice(self.envs) for task in range(self.tasks)] # randomly select tasks from the environment list

        for task in tasks:
            taskLoss = self.ComputeTaskLoss(task) # inner loop learning
            metaLoss = metaLoss + taskLoss

        metaLoss = metaLoss / self.tasks
        
        # meta update
        self.metaOptimizer.zero_grad() # zero the gradients

        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.metaAgent.actorCritic.parameters(), 0.5) # clip the gradients

        # apply the meta gradients
        metaGradients = torch.autograd.grad(metaLoss, self.metaAgent.actorCritic.parameters()) # compute gradients

        for parameter, gradient in zip(self.metaAgent.actorCritic.parameters(), metaGradients):
            parameter.grad = gradient

        self.metaOptimizer.step()

        count += 1
        print(f"Iteration {len(self.metaLoss)} , Loss: {metaLoss.item()}. {count} training iterations completed this session")

    print("Meta Training Complete")

Please note that the ForwardPass function used is as follows:
def ForwardPass(self, state, parameters):

    if parameters is None:
        return self.actorCritic(state)
    # if the parameters are not None, we are using the network for MAML and need to pass the adapted parameters to the forward function
    else:
        return func.functional_call(self.actorCritic, parameters, state)

The ComputeLoss function computes PPO loss.
I was using Meta world's ML10 benchmark for my training and testing set. I used a task distribution of 50 tasks from ML10.
